# I generalised my question, but now the correct answer doesn't help my specific problem

Tags: discussion

This topic is about my question I asked here:
[Chrome 37 calc rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662159/chrome-37-calc-rounding)

I generalised the code a bit because I thought it was Chrome bug and I didn't want to bother people with the exact problem I had. I got a good answer, but since my code is quite different, the solution that is posted doesn't fit for my problem.

Now I'm stuck. I don't think it would be a good idea to change around the whole question to elaborate on my problem. That would also make the answer that was already given irrelevant.

But asking a new question also seems a bit... I dunno. It might be marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask a new question that distinguishes itself from an existing question by explaining why the solution proposed doesn't solve the problem then the question isn't a duplicate, it's merely a similar/related question.

Radically editing a valid question to change it's meaning and invalidate answers is not appropriate.  (Though if the question isn't a valid question on the site, for example if it's closed for lacking sufficient information, then editing in the information to clarify what the actual question is, even if it changes the common interpretations of the question, is appropriate, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.)